# Erro no Manifest após atualização do Android Studio para versão 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

[image: ErroAidl]

Estou iniciando no Android agora e não havia me deparado com este erro anteriormente, já tentei ver outros projetos mas mesmo assim o erro persiste, gostaria de saber o que está causando o erro e como resolvê-lo.

Comment: Tenta ir em clear project e depois rebuild se não resolver nessa activity coloca o nome completo do pacote...

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, embora o rebuild não tenha funcionado, descobri que precisava apenas fazer um "un-inject language or reference" que provavelmente eu havia acrescentado e não percebi.

Answer (score 0):

A respeito deste erro em específico bastou apenas fazer "Un-Inject Language or Reference" e remover a referência ao Aidl que havia.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso o arquivo Manifest deixou de apresentar o erro.